# Why If isset match with syntax is not working

Tags: php, html, debugging

I want if isset `$_POST["items"]` text match with `reject1` text and then echo. My code is not working why?

```
if(isset($_POST["items"])==='reject1'){
   echo 'text match :)';
}
else {
   echo 'not match :(';
}
```

Comment: Isset returns true or false. It cant match `reject1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must write it like that:

```
if(isset($_POST["items"]) && $_POST["items"]==='reject1'){
   echo 'text match :)';
}
else {
   echo 'not match :(';
}
```

Because `isset` is return only **true** or **false**, not an value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if(isset($_POST["items"]) && $_POST["items"]==='reject1'){
   echo 'text match :)';
}
else {
   echo 'not match :(';
}
```

It will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an inner if for the string comparision

```
if(isset($_POST["items"])){
  if ($_POST["items"] ==='reject1'){
    echo 'text match :)';
  } else {
   echo 'not match :(';
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

php isset() returns true or false, so it can't match 'reject1'. If you want to match you should do:

```
if($_POST["items"]==='reject1') {}
```

or if you want to check if the variable exists you can do:

```
if(isset($_POST["items"]) && $_POST["items"]==="reject1") {
echo "text match";} else { echo "not match"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

`isset` returns `TRUE` if a variable is set, or `FALSE` if it isn't. Neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE` are equal to `'reject1'`, so the `if` will never be entered.

You could perform a two phase check - first check if the key is set, and then evaluate its value:

```
if(array_key_exists('items', $_POST) && $_POST['items'] === 'reject1') {
   echo 'text match :)';
} else {
   echo 'not match :(';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or do a one liner:

```
echo (isset($_POST["items"]) && $_POST["items"]==='reject1')? 'text match :)' : 'not match :(';
```

Refs: http://php.net/manual/ro/function.isset.php

> Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL. FALSE otherwise.